# High CPU usage when using AMD GPU instead of Intel HD Graphics

Tags: graphics-card, cpu-usage

I have a strange problem with my CPU (Core i5-4690k), when I'm using my AMD GPU (HD-7870 XFX). Even in games with pretty low system requirements (Counterstrike Global Offensive on the lowest possible graphic settings), my CPU usage goes for full load. If I use the integrated Intel HD Graphic chip instead of the AMD GPU, the CPU usage is much less.

This is my system:

- Intel Core i5-4690k
- Gigabyte Z97-D3H
- AMD Radeon HD-7870 XFX Double Dissipation
- 8GB RAM
- Windows 8.1 Pro x64

I already tried different AMD driver versions, made sure all Intel Chipset drivers are up-to-date, tried a new windows installation as well as re-installing the games. But nothing helped. My cpu cooler is still losing it if I use the AMD GPU. Everything is ok with the Intel HD Graphics.

Comment: How are you determining that your CPU usage is going to full load?

Comment: I'm using Open Hardware Monitor to measure cpu load, temperature and fan speed (especially the fan speed is much higher and therefore annoyingly loud). All of those are higher when using the AMD graphics card rather than the Intel HD graphics. They are not significant higher, more like 5-10 degree celsius temperature and 20% higher cpu load, but it seems strange to me, because the cpu additional has to compute the graphics. So those values should be higher, not lower when using the Intel HD graphcis.

Comment: This actually wouldn't really bother me if the cpu fan speed stayed the same, but the difference is really wide. With the Intel graphics the pc isn't really hearable at all. However, with the amd graphics card, you can hear the cpu fan even when playing with headphones.

Comment: Try running [Process Explorer](live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe) while you're using the Intel and then the AMD GPU and have a look at the GPU usage graph to see what the difference in usage of the GPU is.